# ASP.NET.Core Web API can't connect to MariaDB database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mariadb, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I'm currently developing a ASP.NET Core Web-API which should work on a MariaDB 10.4 database. So far, whenever I start the IIS Server via Visual Studio 2019, no errors or warnings are thrown. The connection to said database is realized by using the EF core framework in combination with the Pomelo.Mysl library. The relevant files look as follows:

*Startup.cs*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using racoon.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql;

namespace racoon
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddDbContext<CollabradorContext>(options => options.UseMySql("Server=localhost;Database=db;User=usr;Password=foo;"));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
}
```

*SampleContext.cs*:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using racoon.Models;
using System.Net.Mime;

namespace racoon.Data
   {
public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public SampleContext(DbContextOptions<SampleContext> options) : base(options) {}

    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get;set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
    }
}
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace racoon.Models
    {
    public class Course
    {
        public long Id;
        public string Name;
        public string Description;
        public int Rating;
    }
}
```

*DbInitalizer.cs*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using racoon.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace racoon.Data
{
    public static class DbInitalizer
{
    public static void Initalize(CollabradorContext context)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Initalize!");
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        if (context.Students.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var courses = new Course[]
        {
            new Course{Id=0,Name="Python",Description="Learn the fundamentals of Python",Rating=0},
            new Course{Id=1,Name="ML",Description="Learn everything about Machine Learning",Rating=0}
        };
        foreach (Course c in courses)
        {
            context.Courses.Add(c);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
}
```

*Program.cs*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using racoon.Data;

namespace racoon
{
    public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        host.Run();
    }

    private static void CreateDbIfNotExists(IHost host)
    {
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

            try
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<SampleContext>();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred creating the DB.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
}
```

Comment: Man first of all you shouln't write your password and user name on public.

Comment: Second, a minimal example is not the ramount of code you posted. Voting to close, as per site rules - provide a MINIMAL example.

Comment: Make sure that you are not using that password anywhere else than locally. It is now out there forever (e.g. it can be seen in the history of the post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use options in the [UseMySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/wiki/Configuration-Options) to mention that you are connecting to a MariaDB instead of the default Mysql DB.

```
services.AddDbContext<CollabradorContext>(options => options      
                .UseMySql("Server=localhost;Database=db;User=usr;Password=foo;",      
                    mysqlOptions =>      
                        mysqlOptions.ServerVersion(new ServerVersion(new Version(10, 4, 6), ServerType.MariaDb))));
```

Comment: This should not be the answer to your issue. While it is true, that you should always use the `ServerVersion` option to specify which version of MySQL or MariaDB you are using, not specifying this should have no effect at all when it comes to establishing a connection to the database. The `ServerVersion` option is only being consulted, when generating SQL queries, and even there only in specific cases. So your issue is probably just fireall/port etc. related. What is the exact exception (including stack trace) that is being thrown? (Or if none is thrown, then what is the issue?)